# MySQL: Join (2 tables) vs single queries (1 table)

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, select

In **PHP**, I have an **array of 11 persons** where **just the ID** of each person is given:

```
$persons = array(1, 3, 39, 72, 17, 20, 102, 99, 77, 2, 982);
```

In my **MySQL database**, there's a table containing **detailed information** about each person:

```
TABLE personInfo
 - ID (integer)
 - name (string)
 - birth date (timestamp)
 - weight (decimal)
 - ...
```

**PROBLEM:**

So now, I want to **select the matching name for each ID in the PHP array**. I can only imagine two solutions to do this:

**1. for-loop:**

```
foreach ($persons as $person) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM personInfo WHERE id = ".$person);
}
```

**2. logical operator OR**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM personInfo WHERE id = 1 OR id = 3 OR id = 39 OR ...");
```

Both **solutions are slow**, aren't they?

But if I had another MySQL table containing the IDs of the PHP array ...

```
TABLE ids
 - ID (integer)
```

... I could **use a join to make a really fast MySQL query**, right?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT a.ID, b.name FROM ids AS a JOIN personInfo AS b ON a.ID = b.ID");
```

**QUESTION:**

Is all this correct so far? If yes: Why is this so? The MySQL query is faster if I have a second table? With only one table it is incredibly slow? What is the fastest way to solve my problem (selecting the names matching the IDs of the PHP array)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have lots of ids (several hundreds or more), feeding the values into a temporary table and joining it is actually faster.

You may want to read this article:

- [**Passing parameters in MySQL: IN list vs. temporary table**](http://explainextended.com/2009/08/18/passing-parameters-in-mysql-in-list-vs-temporary-table/)

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed. So for about 20 parameters both approaches have the same performance. But for about 500 parameters you should prefer the temporary table.

Answer (score 2):

IF you have ID's you should just query the Id's you have. So

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM personInfo WHERE id = 1 OR id = 3 OR id = 39 OR ...");
```

would be right, although I would use

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM personInfo WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4....) )
```

Comment: Thank you, this syntax looks better :)